# Power Automate, Export PowerBI Project to Excel csv max rows 1k

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created a Power Automate workflow, but that outputs the csv to a SharePoint location. However it is restricting the output to 1000 rows only.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Current workflow:

```
On Power BI Button Clicked 
 --> Composes (Input:PowerBI Data) 
      --> Create CSV Table (From: Compose Outputs)
          --> Create File SharePoint (File Content: Create CSV Table Output)
```

Thanks

Rob